# Solution Verification: Regular expression that starts with $a$ and doesn't contain $aba$ pattern.

Tags: solution-verification, regular-language, regular-expressions

> Write a regular expression that starts with $a$ and doesn't contain $aba$ pattern.

**My Solution:** 
If my expression doesn't contain $aba$, then it must not have a $b$ alone in the middle of it before ending, a single $b$ could appear at the end of the word only. So my regular expression will end with $(b+\epsilon)$ to give it a chance to not end with $b$ also.
Now I need to be able to add $abba,abbba,abbbbbbbbaaa$ and expressions with two or more $b$'s, so I thought about it and I can see that I can generate that using the regular expression $(bb+bbb)^*$, because I can reach $5$ and $4$ b's, so I can add two to $4$ and get $6$, can add $2$ to $5$ and get $7$... 

And so with the other constraints I reached this: $a(a+bb+bbb)^*(b+\epsilon)$ 
Would appreciate any feedback, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are any characters other than $a$ or $b$ permitted in the string?  Consider "...then it must not have a b alone in the middle of it before ending."  Consider also "So my regular expression will end with $(b+\epsilon)$ to give it a chance to not end with $b$ also."

Comment: @user2661923 No only $a$ and $b$, sorry for forgetting to write that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct but is obtained a bit gropingly. A more systematic way would be to first calculate the minimal automaton of the language $aA^* \setminus A^*abaA^*$ and then obtain a regular expression from this automaton.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I still haven't reached what a minimal automaton yet in my studies, I will make sure I come back to try it after learning it! thanks alot now I'm excited for that :)